# videojs doesnot play when we change the path of the mp4 .when we navigate its downloads the mp4

Tags: jquery, mp4

I am using a videojs plugin. its a jquery video player plugin which uses flowplayer.
when i put the videojs code it plays the video form there server http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4. but when i replace it with my on web address online or localhost it doesnot play .mp4. My local computer has all the software such as flash,mp4,Apple software,i am running this application on widows7 with visual studio 2010.

Comment: It is nice if important details of your question are repeated in the body of your question and not only in the title. For example the file downloads instead of streaming.

Answer (score 0):

Is your .mp4 encoded for streaming? In order for flash based videos to work, data called "moov" must be moved from the end of the stream to the start. A program called mp4 FastStart can do this for you. Programs like HandBrake have a "web" option that also does this when encoding.